# Extract number and text from string with RegExp exec Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a number and text from strings like those: 171Toberin, [171]Toberin or [171] Toberin.

I have this RegExp `/(?<code>\d+)(?<name>\w+)/u`, and this RegExp only works with 171Toberin.

Comment: Maybe just `s.match(/\w+/g)`? Or, `s.match(/\d+|\p{L}+/gu)` and suchlike. Following your logic, add `\W*` between the two groups, try `/(?<code>\d+)\W*(?<name>\w+)/u`

Comment: Do you want to store the number and the text in two different variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below regex to remove all non alphanumeric characters.

```js
let string = '171Toberin, [171]Toberin or [171]';
console.log(string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
```

Or use the below to extract the alphanumeric characters from string.

```js
let string = '171Toberin, [171]Toberin or [171]';
console.log(string.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g));
```

Or if you want to extract numbers and strings in separate array then use the below one.

```js
let string = '171Toberin, [171]Toberin or [171]';
console.log(string.match(/[0-9]+/g));
console.log(string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this: `(?<code>\d+)[^\d\w]*(?<name>\w+)/ug`

It works with the entire sentence: *171Toberin, [171]Toberin or [171] Toberin.*

Returning 3 matches. You can try it at https://regex101.com/

With `[^\d\w]*` you omit possible numbers and words in between. With `g` flag you return all matches.